# How to import a ms stream video URL link into HTML?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, video-streaming, videogular

I have an angularjs app and a url for a MS Stream video. How can I embed this video into my page? The user should paste this link into the page and embed the video. This is my js code:

```
  let video = document.createElement("video");
        video.src = videoUrl;
        video.load();
        video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
          scope.myContent._videoConfig = {
            sources: [{
              src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(videoUrl),
              type: "video/mp4"
            }]
          };
          scope.$apply();
          scope.myContent.url = videoUrl;
        });
```

I does not throw an error but I reckon the load() statement does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

If it’s an mp4 just set src on the video tag. If it’s not an mp4, you need use a player like video.js.